# If $X$ is a LCHS and $K, O \subseteq X$ with $K$ cpt & $O$ open, then $\exists U$ open s.t. $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq O$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm having trouble fully understanding the proof of this statement.

> Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff topological space.  Then if $K$ is a compact subset of $X$ and $O$ is any open subset of $X$ containing $K$, $\exists$ an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \text{ compact} \subseteq O$, with $\overline{U}$ being the closure of $U$.

Here is how I was taught the proof goes:

Let $K \subseteq X$ be compact, and let $O \subseteq X$ be open such that $K \subseteq O$.  Then since $O$ is open, $O^{c}$ is closed.  But $O^{c}$ closed and $K$ compact implies we can find $U, V$ open such that $K \subseteq U$ and $O^{c} \subseteq V$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$ (this is because locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces are regular).  But if $O^{c} \subseteq V$, then $V^{c} \subseteq O$.

Since $V$ is open, $V^{c}$ is closed.  Also, $U \cap V = \emptyset \implies U \subseteq V^{c}$.  Since $V^{c}$ is closed, we have the closure of $U$, $\overline{U}$, is contained in $V^{c}$.  So, we have $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq O$.  We can assume $\overline{U}$ is compact, and so we are done.

**First question:**  Is there an easy way to prove that a locally compact Hausdorff topological space is regular?  I wasn't able to do so on my own.

**Second question:** Why can we assume $\overline{U}$ is compact at the end?  Does it have anything to do with the space being locally compact?

Comment: Corollary 3.4 is a proof showing that a LCHS is regular. It doesn't look too bad. Sorry I can't be more help, my topology is pretty rusty. Also for what it's worth, compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are always compact. http://books.google.com/books?id=fvCpXrube5wC&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=proof+that+a+locally+compact+hausdorff+space+is+regular&source=bl&ots=QDG_AUgBdF&sig=_savgqTaGRYdC-9aNTAKfk9rCNY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iU4FVOHfH4rCggSLsYKoDQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=proof%20that%20a%20locally%20compact%20hausdorff%20space%20is%20regular&f=false

Comment: @user166967 Thanks for the reference.  I couldn't find much when I tried googling it myself.  Also, did you mean "compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are always *closed*"?  If so, this doesn't imply closed subsets are necessarily compact. :(

Comment: @user166967 that is exactly what I meant haha. It may not be the result we need, but it could help us get there.

Comment: @layman, could you explain how is that being in a regular space helps you to find  open subsets $U$ and $V$ such that one contain a compact and other a closed and $U\cap V=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: AFAIK, the regular space allows you to separate a point and a closed set.

Comment: @Isa please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877276/under-which-t-axiom-can-you-separate-disjoint-closed-and-compact-set-compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** In this [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFcQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpersonal.stevens.edu%2F~nstrigul%2FMA651%2FLecture9.pdf&ei=asIFVKmfNcanggTb1YLwDg&usg=AFQjCNFYjSLMVlfqK55xvQThxJRw0XyG-Q&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY), you can find your desired proof. It invokes the one point compactification and I think that it is a standard one.

I would like to note that, in your case, where you are trying to separate a compact set from a closed set, the proof can be done without invoking regularity (at least, it does not use it explicitly). For the proof, take a look in Theorem 2.7. of [Rudin's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542341).

**Second question:** Yes, it is related with locally compactness. Indeed, once $K$ is compact, you can find a open neighbourhood of $K$ with compact closure. Indeed, for each $p\in K$, there is $p\in U_p$ open with $\overline{U}_p$ compact. The Family $\{U_p\}_{p\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, thus, we can assume that $$K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N U_{p_i},$$

for some finite $N$, therefore, $$K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N \overline{U_{p_i}},$$

which is compact.

Comment: Yes, but is this compact set you found contained within $V^{c}$?

Comment: Also, is $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U_{p_{i}}$ contained in $V^{c}$?  It seems to me that the $U$'s you found are independent of the $U$ and $V$ I picked such that $U \subseteq V^{c}$.

Comment: That's not the argument. I will leave to you, to think more on the problem. After some thought, come here and I will help you again.

Comment: What is wrong about that argument?  Since $K$ was compact, and $O$ is open and containing $K$, then $K$ and $O^{c}$ are disjoint closed sets (with $K$ compact).  Then we find $U$, $V$ open and disjoint such that $K \subseteq U$, $O^{c} \subseteq V$.  But then $V^{c} \subseteq O$, and so we have $K \subseteq U \subseteq V^{c}$.  Since $V^{c}$ is closed, then we know $\overline{U} \subseteq V^{c}$.  So all that is left to show is that $\overline{U}$ is compact, which is what we just "assumed" without me understanding why.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your misunrdestood me. I do not refer to the argument in the question. I refered to the argument in your first comment. I do not said in any moment that $\cup_{i=1}^N U_{p_i}$ is the open set $U$, that your are looking for.

Comment: Can you give me some more insight into what I should be thinking about?  It seems like the argument you gave me in the answer is independent of the proof I posted, so I am not sure what I should be thinking about.  I understand the proof I posted, and I understand what you wrote in your answer, but I do not see how they can interact, because you picked a different open set than the $U$ I found in my proof.

Comment: Well ok, however, be advised that if you have thinked a little bit on the problem, you might have solved it by your own. Consider your $U$ in your proof and my finite collection $\cup_{i=1}^N U_{p_i}$. What can you say about the set $$U\cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^N U_{p_i}\right)$$

Comment: I kept thinking about it after reading the first sentence of your comment, but I wasn't able to get it.  Then I read your hint, and here is what I understand (if it is right):

Comment: Clearly, $U \cap \left ( \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U_{p_{i}} \right ) = \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U \cap U_{p_{i}}$ is open.  Also, since $\overline{\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U \cap U_{p_{i}}} \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} \overline{U \cap U_{p_{i}}} $, and we have $\overline{U_{p_{i}} \cap U}$ is a closed subset of the cpt set $\overline{U}$ implies $\overline{U_{p_{i}} \cap U}$ is cpt, and this the finite union is compact.  Also, $\overline{\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U \cap U_{p_{i}}}$ is a closed subset of the cpt set $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} \overline{U \cap U_{p_{i}}}$

Comment: Which implies $\overline{\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U \cap U_{p_{i}}}$ is compact.  So, we found our open set containing $K$ such that its closure is compact and contained in $O$.  Namely, $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{N} U \cap U_{p_{i}}$ is our open set.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea and that's why in your proof, it can be assumed that $\overline{U}$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. When you have time, take a look in Rudin's proof also.

Comment: Ok, I will today.

Comment: Actually, my argument is flawed.  I used that $\overline{U}$ is compact, even though that is what I wanted to show.  I should have said $\overline{U_{p_{i}} \cap U} \subseteq \overline{U_{p_{i}}}$, a compact set...