# Under which $T$ axiom can you separate disjoint closed and compact set? Compact and compact set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

I am trying to figure out what is the lowest separation axiom needed that allows you to

1. separate disjoint closed and compact set **via disjoint open sets**, and
2. separate disjoint compact and compact sets **via disjoint open sets**.

> **Claim**: Disjoint closed sets and compact sets in $T_3$ space and above can be
>   separated via disjoint open sets

Pf. Take disjoint closed and compact sets $C,K$ respectively. Then since the space is $T_3$ (more importantly, regular), we can take disjoint open sets $V_k, U_k$ such that $k \in V_k$, where $k \in K$, and $C \subset U_k$

Then finite union of $V_k$ covers $K$, and finite intersection of $U_k$ covers $C$, those are disjoint open sets by construction.

---

What about compact sets? Is Hausdorfness enough?

> **Claim**: Disjoint compact sets in $T_2$ space and above can be
>   separated via disjoint open sets

Let $K_1,K_2$ be disjoint compact sets in Hausdorff space.

Then $\forall x \in K_1, y \in K_2$, there exists disjoint open sets $U_x, V_x$ such that $x \in U_x, y \in V_x$.

Then $\{U_x|x \in X\}, \{V_x| x \in X\}$ are open covers of $K_1, K_2$ with finite subcovers $\{U_{x_i}|x_i \in X, i \in {1, \ldots, n}\}, \{V_{x_i}|x_i \in X, i \in {1, \ldots, n}\}$.

We need to show that they are disjoint, let $z \in \cup U_{x_i} \cap \cup V_{x_i}$, then $z \in U_{x_i}, \forall x_i \in X$, and $V_{x_i}, \forall x_i \in X$. This is impossible since $U_{x_i}$ and $V_{x_i}$ are disjoint $\forall x_i \in X$

---

Are the above characterizations correct? Are there more generalizations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your results are more than right, they are basic :-) see, for instance Theorem 3.1.6 from Engelking’s “General topology” below. The separation assumptions cannot be weakened, because if each two compact subsets of a space can be separated by disjoint sets then the space is Hausdorff, similarly it the other case we have the regularity.

[image]